# Register more than one MPRIS player with GDBus

Tags: c, glib, dbus, gdbus

I want to register more than one media player with glib. Minimal (non-)working example is [here](https://bitbucket.org/f1u77y/mpris-many-players). As I can understand the [specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/mpris-spec/latest/), I should export many objects with the one name `/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2` and that's strange.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple media players in the same process, you would need to open one D-Bus connection to the session bus for *each* of them, and expose a separate `/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2` object on each connection. You can’t expose multiple objects at the same path on a single D-Bus connection.

Be aware that if you’re using [`g_bus_get_sync()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GDBusConnection.html#g-bus-get-sync) to get a bus connection, it will return a singleton session bus connection — i.e. the same connection every time you call it. In order to establish multiple connections to the session bus, you will need to connect using [`g_dbus_address_get_for_bus_sync()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gio-D-Bus-Addresses.html#g-dbus-address-get-for-bus-sync) and [`g_dbus_connection_new_for_address()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GDBusConnection.html#g-dbus-connection-new-for-address-sync), as stated in the documentation for `g_bus_get_sync()`:

> The returned object is a singleton, that is, shared with other callers
>   of `g_bus_get()` and `g_bus_get_sync()` for `bus_type`. In the event that
>   you need a private message bus connection, use
>   `g_dbus_address_get_for_bus_sync()` and
>   `g_dbus_connection_new_for_address()`.

Comment: Thanks! But the documentation says "This constructor can only be used to initiate client-side connections" for `g_dbus_connection_new_for_address_sync ()`. As I could understand, I need to initiate server-side connection.

Comment: ‘Client-side’ as opposed to the `dbus-daemon`, which is the server side in this case. You are creating a *service* (some D-Bus interfaces at a well-known name), not a *server* (a message routing bus). So `g_dbus_connection_new_for_address_sync()` is definitely appropriate for your use case.